# Find the number of previous elements in vector until current value was equal or exceeded

Tags: r, loops, vector

For every element in a vector, I want to calculate the number of previous elements until I reach an element that is equal to or exceeds the value of the current element.

This is my vector:

```
CPC= c(25382.6, 30044.9,    22664.4,    30752.3,    21896.9,    24173.1,    29777.9,    9021.1, 8175.1, 9005.8, 5314.2, 4274.1, 3759.1, 5043.1, 5080.9, 6444.4, 6097.6, 8004.2, 6004.7, 6468.9, 5104.7, 5985.5, 8343.7, 8582,   7494.3, 6088.9, 4372.7, 4298.6, 4553.2, 5742)
```

I have tried something like this, which is not working

```
ROC = NULL  #Create vector to store values
for (i in seq(1:length(CPC))
     while(CPC[i])<CPC[i-1]
        ROC[i] <- ifelse((CPC[i] < CPC[i-1]),1,0)
```

The output I am looking for is a vector (ROC) of same lenght as the original one (CPC), so that every element corresponds to the element on the same place in the original vector. ROC[i] would for CPC[i] give the number of previous elements in the CPC vector until the value is equal to or bigger than CPC[i]. For some elements, there are no pervious elements that has a higher or equal value and this would still need to be saved in the output, for example as a NA.

It would look like this:

```
ROC 
NA,NA,1,NA,1,2,3,1,1,2... etc
```

Comment: Please provide your expected output for this example. It is not clear to me if you want the index or the value or a sum or something else.

Comment: Does any of the two solutions come close. I edited my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prs <- unlist(lapply(1:(length(CPC)), 
        function(x) {
          less_or_eq <- CPC[1 : x] <=  CPC[x]
          if(all(less_or_eq))
            return(0)
          inds <- which(less_or_eq == 0)
          return(x - inds[length(inds)])
          } ))

prs
# 0  0  1  0  1  2  3  1  1  2  1  1  1  3  4  6  1  8  1  2  1  2 13
# 14  1  1  1  1  3 4
```

Using for loop

```
res <- numeric(length(CPC))

for (i in 1 : length(CPC)) {
  less_or_eq <- CPC[1 : i] <=  CPC[i]
  if (all(less_or_eq)) {
    res[i] <- 0
  } else {
    inds <- which(less_or_eq == 0)
    res[i] <- (i - inds[length(inds)])
  }
} 

res
#[1]  0  0  1  0  1  2  3  1  1  2  1  1  1  3  4  6  1  8  1  2  1  2 13
#[24] 14  1  1  1  1  3  4
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I think it's very close from what I want to do, but it doesn't give exactly the output that I try to achive. I updated my question and tried to clarify what I'm looking for. So I want to count backwards in the CPC vector, and find the number of elements until I reach the same or a bigger value. If this element doesn't exist I want to replace it by a 0 like you did or NA. I can not figgure out exactly what your code calculates, but as I understand it it calculates forward in the vector?

Comment: Well, it seems to me what I am doing is what you are saying what you want to do... may try to get manually the output you want to get and let me know how my answer differ from it.

Comment: If I look manually, the output that I would expect would be like this:

Comment: `#[1] 0,0,1,0,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,4,6,1... etc`

Comment: @Nicolle, see the edited solution. Looks like you got the 14th wrong in the manual calculation.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much! Yes, I got the 14th wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your output requirement is not very clear. The main part is to find where the difference (`diff`) changes to from negative to positive (meaning that the previous value is less than or equal to the current one. We create the groups based on that and count the length of each group, i.e.

```
tapply(CPC, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(CPC) >= 0)), length)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
# 1  2  2  1  3  4  1  1  2  2  2  1  1  5  1  1 

#or take the cumulative sum of the above,

cumsum(tapply(CPC, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(CPC) >= 0)), length))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
# 1  3  5  6  9 13 14 15 17 19 21 22 23 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think something similar to the first part could work, I would like to find where the difference changes from negative to positive as you say and save the lenght of that. Then I would like to save all these lenghts in a vector of same lenght as the first one so that every element corresponds to the element on the same place of the other vector. I'm sorry that my question was not very clear, I tried to do some clearifications.